# Class read after the component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm newbie with Angular.
I'm trying to save data in a class to read them into a component. I noticed that before the class is completely read, the component hurries the results, which have not yet been produced, then printing an error message:

[image: Console output]

Only later it prints the values correctly. But only and exclusively within the `subscribe`, as can be seen from the image.
This is my class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherForecastApiService } from '../weatherForecastApiService/weather-forecast-api.service';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WeatherClass {
    public weather: WeatherFeature;

    constructor(
        private wfas: WeatherForecastApiService,
    ) {
        this.wfas.getItalyWeatherData('Pisa').subscribe((response) => {
            const ks: string[] = ['name', 'main', 'temp'];
            this.weather = {
                cityName: response[ks[0]],
                degrees: response[ks[1]][ks[2]] - 273.15,
            }; 
            console.log('clean print', this.weather.cityName);
            console.log('clean print', this.weather.degrees);
        });
    }
    public showValues() {
        console.log('undefined print in component', this.weather.cityName);
        console.log('undefined print in component', this.weather.degrees);
    }
}
```

And this is my (premature) component:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherClass } from '../weatherObject/weather-class';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-weather-forecast',
    templateUrl: './weather-forecast.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./weather-forecast.component.scss'],
})
export class WeatherForecastComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(
        private weather: WeatherClass,
    ) {}
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.weather.showValues();
    }
}
```

I remember that something similar happened to me with javascript, but the context was easier to solve (that it was asynchronous?).
I am very curious to clear this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1260204)

Comment: The simplest way would be to use your api class directly and set your "class" values in your component. Right now it looks like you're trying to use it like a service but using it like a class and these concepts are similar but not exactly the same in the angular world. I gave an example solution below, but there would be many other ways to solve it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.wfas.getItalyWeatherData` is an observable and is asynchronous so there it is likely that your cityName and degree is never set by the time `showValue(`) method is called even though you have it in ngAfterViewInit.

A solution would be for you to have a subject in your WeatherClass which you could listen to (by subscribing to it) inside of your WeatherForecastComponent component. (consider BehaviorSubject as they hold a default value and let you retrieve a value on first subscription)

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WeatherClass {

    public weatherFeature = new BehaviorSubject<WeatherFeature>(undefined);

    constructor(
        private wfas: WeatherForecastApiService,
    ) {
        this.wfas.getItalyWeatherData('Pisa').subscribe((response) => {
            const ks: string[] = ['name', 'main', 'temp'];
            // This emits the new values for use to any subscribers.
            this.weatherFeature.next({
                cityName: response[ks[0]],
                degrees: response[ks[1]][ks[2]] - 273.15,
            }); 
        });
    }
}
```

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-weather-forecast',
    templateUrl: './weather-forecast.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./weather-forecast.component.scss'],
})
export class WeatherForecastComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    public weather: WeatherFeature;

    constructor(
        private weatherClass: WeatherClass,
    ) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // the subscription here will get the value or any future emitted values.
        this.weatherClass.weatherFeature.subscribe(
            (weatherFeature) => this.weather = weatherFeature
        );
    }
}
```

So in this example in your component i added a property to hold the value you where trying to get.

in your weather class I've added a behavior subject so you can subscribe to this to know when you can get a value for use.

To keep things named cleanly I recommend renaming your WeatherClass to WeatherService :) check out Angular Style guide when you have questions it's a fantastic resource to get used to the framework.

https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#service-names

Comment: I'd say that it is a very good solution. I'd like to ask you something else... What you did inside `next`, is to create an `interface` on the fly?

Comment: The `this.weatherFeature.next(...);` code in the next is a literal object that is the same "shape" as your `WeatherFeature` class. You could use an interface as the type instead or you could use an instance object `this.weatherFeature.next(new WeatherFeature( /* some args here */))` :)

Comment: I found this solution very useful. He gave me input to study 'BehaviorSubject' thoroughly! :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that getItalyWeatherData does not complete before you call showValues. A common approach would be something among the lines of:

WeatherClass ->

```
getItalyWeatherData() {
  return this.wfas.getItalyWeatherData('Pisa');
}
```

WeatherForecastComponent ->

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.weather.getItalyWeatherData().subscribe(res => {same code as the one you currently have});
}
```

This way the moment the API call resolves the data will be displayed.

Comment: It works, ok... but it's not strictly what I want. I accepted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58731264/8275210) because it is closer to the type of structuring of the code I was looking for.